# Cakephp, Error when executing command cake extract in terminal

Tags: cakephp, console, terminal, internationalization

I get the following error when executing in Terminal the following command "cake extract":

```
Error: Class ExtractShell could not be loaded.
```

I have made sure that I'm in the right path and also all other commands I've executed work great like cake bake for example.

Do you have any ideas ...

Comment: Make sure file permissions allow apache user to read the extract.php file.  Can you turn up the PHP error_reporting level to get a more verbose output?

Comment: How can I do that? Do I need to enter to php.ini for a more verbose output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I got it.

First of all in cakephp 1.2 & 1.3 to create the pot files you need to execute the

```
cake i18n extract
```

However first the folders need to be created: app/locale/eng/LC_MESSAGES
And inside each language folder the file default.po has to be available (even empty)
Then cake generates a default.pot file which can be imported with poedit and then saved to generate the required .po and .mo files.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the file /cake/console/libs/extract?

As far as I know, extract is only available in cake 1.3, are you using the beta? In 1.2 branch extract is not present.

Comment: Actually it is in /cake/console/libs/tasks/extract.php and yes I am using 1.3. What do you think is the problem?

Comment: Oh, now I get. It's a task, not a shell extension, it means (afaik) that you have to use it in your own shell plugin. Take a look at i18n.php, it has a $task variable which hold "extract".

But I really do not know how it should work...

Comment: Maybe, If I understand right, you have to use cake i18n with some special parameters to acheive what you used to do by cake extract...

Comment: I think you're right. i18n is the replacement of extract or at least what it is used to generate the pot files. However when I run the i18n I get the following error (several times): Undefined offset:  0 in /cake/console/libs/tasks/extract.php on line 129 and also on line 131. I'm not sure why I get that... if it rings any bells please let me know. Thanks